# Iterrtuples + GeoPandas DataFrame + Plotting

Tags: python, geopandas

I am not well versed in Python (or GeoPandas) and I am currently having a simple issue with plotting. To spot some inconsistencies, I need to individually plot all the geometries in the geodataframe. If you are wondering why I am using enumerate() and itertuples() is because I need to find where the inconsistencies are (but I haven't implemented yet in the code!).

Here's the code:

```
for i, row in enumerate(faci_shp.itertuples(index=False)):
  row.plot()
```

I get this error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> 1 choma_shp = faci_shp.iloc[facilities, :].copy()
> 2 for i, row in enumerate(faci_shp.itertuples(index=False)):
> ----> 3   row.plot()
>
> AttributeError: 'Pandas' object has no attribute 'plot'

Is it clear?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The GeoDataframe

```
gdf.plot()
```

[image]

Now, what you want to do is to plot the geometry of each individual rows, not the rows.
With your solution, you get the entire row with the geometry and the attributes as [Pandas](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/) dataframes ( hence the error `AttributeError: 'Pandas' object has no attribute 'plot'`)`

```
for  row in gdf.itertuples():
    print(row)
Pandas(id=1, geometry=<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x107380160>)
Pandas(id=2, geometry=<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x11d87e198>)
Pandas(id=3, geometry=<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x107380080>)
```

With only the row geometry:

```
for row in gdf.itertuples():
    print(row.geometry)
POLYGON ((0.7267114943073861 0.7347155512795274, 0.7263063833454005 0.7264693282083019, 0.7250949518994638 0.7183025207730966, 0.7230888667166361 0.7102937797939431, 0.7203074474938659 0.7025202338244942, 0.7167774808187467 0.6950567463618882, 0.712532962200036 0.687975194870347, 0.7076147686723221 0.681343778561904, 0.7020702651278347 0.6752263616007105, 0.6959528481666412 0.669681858056223, 0.6893214318581983 0.6647636645285091, 0.6822398803666569 0.6605191459097985, 0.6747763929040509 0.6569891792346793, 0.667002846934602 0.6542077600119089, 0.6589941059554486 0.6522016748290813, 0.6508272985202432 0.6509902433831446, 0.6425810754490178 0.6505851324211589, 0.6343348523777924 0.6509902433831446, 0.6261680449425869 0.6522016748290812, 0.6181593039634335 0.6542077600119088, 0.6103857579939848 0.6569891792346791, 0.6029222705313786 0.6605191459097983, 0.5958407190398374 0.6647636645285089, 0.5892093027313944 0.6696818580562229, 0.5830918857702009 0.6752263616007104, 0.5775473822257134 0.6813437785619039, 0.5726291886979994 0.6879751948703468, 0.5683846700792887 0.695056746361888, 0.5648547034041695 0.7025202338244942, 0.5620732841813992 0.710293779793943, 0.5600671989985716 0.7183025207730964, 0.5588557675526349 0.7264693282083019, 0.5584506565906492 0.7347155512795273, 0.5588557675526348 0.7429617743507528, 0.5600671989985715 0.7511285817859581, 0.5620732841813992 0.7591373227651116, 0.5648547034041694 0.7669108687345605, 0.5683846700792886 0.7743743561971665, 0.5726291886979993 0.7814559076887079, 0.5775473822257133 0.7880873239971509, 0.5830918857702008 0.7942047409583444, 0.5892093027313942 0.7997492445028316, 0.5958407190398372 0.8046674380305456, 0.6029222705313784 0.8089119566492562, 0.6103857579939844 0.8124419233243755, 0.6181593039634333 0.8152233425471458, 0.6261680449425866 0.8172294277299734, 0.6343348523777921 0.8184408591759101, 0.6425810754490174 0.8188459701378958, 0.6508272985202428 0.8184408591759103, 0.6589941059554483 0.8172294277299735, 0.6670028469346015 0.8152233425471458, 0.6747763929040504 0.8124419233243756, 0.6822398803666566 0.8089119566492566, 0.6893214318581978 0.804667438030546, 0.6959528481666408 0.799749244502832, 0.7020702651278342 0.7942047409583446, 0.7076147686723216 0.7880873239971511, 0.7125329622000357 0.7814559076887084, 0.7167774808187464 0.774374356197167, 0.7203074474938657 0.7669108687345609, 0.723088866716636 0.7591373227651121, 0.7250949518994636 0.7511285817859589, 0.7263063833454004 0.7429617743507535, 0.7267114943073861 0.734715551279528, 0.7267114943073861 0.7347155512795274))
POLYGON ((0.8574398561225293 0.7758907160551732, 0.8570132693400829 0.7672073426158391, 0.8557376172566549 0.7586075948095404, 0.8536251850991509 0.7501742929087525, 0.8506963167440207 0.7419886542208913, 0.8469792187946064 0.7341295109212465, 0.8425096889361334 0.7266725508560383, 0.8373307711844322 0.7196895886270837, 0.8314923413485362 0.713247873977923, 0.8250506266993756 0.707409444142027, 0.818067664470421 0.7022305263903258, 0.8106107044052128 0.6977609965318528, 0.8027515611055679 0.6940438985824384, 0.7945659224177068 0.6911150302273082, 0.7861326205169188 0.6890025980698042, 0.7775328727106202 0.6877269459863762, 0.768849499271286 0.6873003592039298, 0.7601661258319519 0.6877269459863762, 0.7515663780256533 0.6890025980698042, 0.7431330761248652 0.6911150302273081, 0.7349474374370041 0.6940438985824384, 0.7270882941373593 0.6977609965318526, 0.7196313340721511 0.7022305263903257, 0.7126483718431964 0.7074094441420269, 0.7062066571940357 0.7132478739779228, 0.7003682273581396 0.7196895886270835, 0.6951893096064385 0.7266725508560381, 0.6907197797479654 0.7341295109212463, 0.6870026817985511 0.7419886542208911, 0.6840738134434209 0.7501742929087523, 0.6819613812859169 0.7586075948095403, 0.6806857292024888 0.767207342615839, 0.6802591424200425 0.7758907160551731, 0.6806857292024888 0.7845740894945074, 0.6819613812859169 0.7931738373008059, 0.6840738134434208 0.801607139201594, 0.6870026817985511 0.8097927778894551, 0.6907197797479654 0.8176519211891, 0.6951893096064384 0.8251088812543083, 0.7003682273581395 0.8320918434832628, 0.7062066571940355 0.8385335581324236, 0.7126483718431962 0.8443719879683195, 0.7196313340721509 0.8495509057200207, 0.727088294137359 0.8540204355784937, 0.7349474374370037 0.857737533527908, 0.7431330761248649 0.8606664018830382, 0.7515663780256528 0.8627788340405422, 0.7601661258319515 0.8640544861239703, 0.7688494992712857 0.8644810729064166, 0.7775328727106198 0.8640544861239703, 0.7861326205169183 0.8627788340405422, 0.7945659224177064 0.8606664018830383, 0.8027515611055674 0.8577375335279082, 0.8106107044052123 0.8540204355784939, 0.8180676644704206 0.8495509057200209, 0.8250506266993751 0.8443719879683198, 0.8314923413485358 0.8385335581324239, 0.8373307711844318 0.8320918434832633, 0.842509688936133 0.8251088812543087, 0.8469792187946061 0.8176519211891006, 0.8506963167440205 0.8097927778894558, 0.8536251850991508 0.8016071392015947, 0.8557376172566548 0.7931738373008067, 0.8570132693400828 0.7845740894945081, 0.8574398561225293 0.775890716055174, 0.8574398561225293 0.7758907160551732))
POLYGON ((0.8280058963471173 0.6682822096820413, 0.8276007853851317 0.6600359866108159, 0.826389353939195 0.6518691791756106, 0.8243832687563672 0.6438604381964571, 0.8216018495335971 0.6360868922270082, 0.8180718828584779 0.6286234047644021, 0.8138273642397672 0.6215418532728609, 0.8089091707120533 0.6149104369644179, 0.8033646671675658 0.6087930200032244, 0.7972472502063723 0.603248516458737, 0.7906158338979294 0.5983303229310231, 0.7835342824063881 0.5940858043123125, 0.7760707949437821 0.5905558376371932, 0.7682972489743332 0.5877744184144229, 0.7602885079951798 0.5857683332315953, 0.7521217005599744 0.5845569017856586, 0.7438754774887489 0.5841517908236729, 0.7356292544175236 0.5845569017856586, 0.7274624469823181 0.5857683332315952, 0.7194537060031647 0.5877744184144228, 0.7116801600337159 0.5905558376371931, 0.7042166725711098 0.5940858043123123, 0.6971351210795685 0.5983303229310228, 0.6905037047711255 0.6032485164587369, 0.684386287809932 0.6087930200032243, 0.6788417842654446 0.6149104369644178, 0.6739235907377306 0.6215418532728607, 0.6696790721190199 0.6286234047644019, 0.6661491054439007 0.6360868922270082, 0.6633676862211304 0.643860438196457, 0.6613616010383028 0.6518691791756104, 0.6601501695923661 0.6600359866108159, 0.6597450586303804 0.6682822096820412, 0.6601501695923659 0.6765284327532668, 0.6613616010383027 0.6846952401884721, 0.6633676862211304 0.6927039811676255, 0.6661491054439006 0.7004775271370745, 0.6696790721190198 0.7079410145996805, 0.6739235907377304 0.7150225660912218, 0.6788417842654445 0.7216539823996648, 0.6843862878099319 0.7277713993608583, 0.6905037047711253 0.7333159029053455, 0.6971351210795683 0.7382340964330596, 0.7042166725711095 0.7424786150517702, 0.7116801600337156 0.7460085817268894, 0.7194537060031645 0.7487900009496598, 0.7274624469823178 0.7507960861324874, 0.7356292544175232 0.7520075175784241, 0.7438754774887486 0.7524126285404098, 0.752121700559974 0.7520075175784242, 0.7602885079951794 0.7507960861324875, 0.7682972489743327 0.7487900009496598, 0.7760707949437816 0.7460085817268896, 0.7835342824063878 0.7424786150517706, 0.790615833897929 0.7382340964330599, 0.797247250206372 0.733315902905346, 0.8033646671675654 0.7277713993608586, 0.8089091707120528 0.7216539823996651, 0.8138273642397669 0.7150225660912224, 0.8180718828584775 0.707941014599681, 0.8216018495335968 0.7004775271370749, 0.8243832687563671 0.6927039811676261, 0.8263893539391948 0.6846952401884728, 0.8276007853851316 0.6765284327532675, 0.8280058963471173 0.668282209682042, 0.8280058963471173 0.6682822096820413))[Shapely][3]
```

Now you can plot each row geometry ([Shapely](https://pypi.org/project/Shapely/) geometry) individually with [matplotlib](https://pypi.org/project/matplotlib/)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6))
for row in gdf.itertuples():
     ax.plot(*row.geometry.exterior.xy)
ax.axis('equal')
```

[image]

And [descartes](https://pypi.org/project/descartes/)

```
import descartes
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6))
for row in gdf.itertuples():
  ax.plot(*row.geometry.exterior.xy)
  ax.add_patch(descartes.PolygonPatch(row.geometry, fc='blue', alpha=0.2))
ax.axis('equal')
```

[image]